# how can i run commands in a docker container?

Tags: ubuntu, python, docker

i am trying to get any python commands to work on my container on docker as i am trying to install a requirement for a module for odoo i dont know why and as there is minimal documentation (as far as i can tell)

```
sudo docker exec -it veivaa-odoo1 /bin/bash
odoo@veivaa-odoo1:/$ docker-compose run pip install py-asterisk
bash: docker-compose: command not found
odoo@veivaa-odoo1:/$ docker-compose run veivaa-odoo1 apt-get update
bash: docker-compose: command not found
odoo@veivaa-odoo1:/$ sudo docker-compose run veivaa-odoo1 apt-get update
bash: sudo: command not found
odoo@veivaa-odoo1:/$ docker-compose run veivaa-odoo1 /bin/bash
bash: docker-compose: command not found
odoo@veivaa-odoo1:/$ docker run -it veivaa-odoo1 pip install py-asterisk
bash: docker: command not found
odoo@veivaa-odoo1:/$ sudo docker-compose -f build.yml run cli
bash: sudo: command not found
```

please help

Comment: The problem is you don't understand what you're doing ;) Use plain docker first, without docker-compose. Once you get it, read up what docker-compose does.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done:

```
sudo docker exec -it veivaa-odoo1 /bin/bash
```

... your input goes to the bash interpreter you started in the container, and so runs with the container environment. `docker-compose` is a command to manage containers, and of course is not normally available inside containers. Likewise, by default the id inside the container is root (in the container environment) so you don't need `sudo`.  What could have worked is a plain `pip install py-asterisk`. However, this is not the proper way to install software in a container, the proper way is to create an image that derives a base image, add applications to it, and then run that image:

You create a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM somebaseimage
RUN pip install py-asterisk
```

Then you create the image from it:

```
docker build -t mynewimage .
```

Then you can run your image:

```
docker run mynewimage
```

You normally want to use `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` to define what the container run when it starts.